# apply decorator in front of call and not in front of definition

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-decorators

I'm currently trying to use decorators to implement the functionality to wait for some assert calls in my unittests before i finally let the `AssertionError` bubble up.

Currently my decorator looks like this:

```
def waitUpTo(seconds):
    def decorator(assert_func_to_decorate):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for _ in range(seconds):
                print(datetime.now())
                try:
                    return(assert_func_to_decorate(*args,**kwargs))
                except AssertionError:
                    time.sleep(1)
            return(assert_func_to_decorate(*args,**kwargs))
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And it works quite well when i call and use it like this:

```
waitUpTo(3)(self.assertRegexpMatches)('notHello', r'Hello')
```

But somehow this calls tend to get a little bit long.
Is there a way to use the `@` syntax for this before the actual call to the function and not before the definition of it?

Ideally such a thing would be nice:

```
@waitUpTo(3)
self.assertRegexpMatches('notHello', r'Hello')
```

Comment: No, there's no way to do that - the `@` decorator syntax is *specifically* for method/class/function definitions, **not** calls.

Comment: Mmh, ok and i assume theres no other shortcut or syntactic sugar i could use, or is there one?

Comment: You can split it across two lines: `decorated_func = decorator(deco_args)(func); decorated_func(func_args)`. This also allows you to e.g. factor the decoration out a loop. Otherwise no, there is no other syntax for applying decorators.

Comment: Yeah i know but as in this case the argument of the decorator will change quite often depending on what i want to test, this is a little bit cumbersome, but thanks for the recommendation